# Regexp does not match utf8 characters in words (\w+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Why does the following code return nil:

```
'The name of the city is: Ørbæk'.match(/:\s\w+/)
#=> nil
```

When I would expect it to return `"Ørbæk"`

I have tried setting the `#encoding=utf-8` in the beginning of the document but it does not change anything.

PS. Ø and Æ are danish letters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metacharacters `\w` is equivalent to the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`; matches only alphabets, digits, and `_`.

Instead use the character property `\p{Word}`:

```
'The name of the city is: Ørbæk'.match(/:\s\p{Word}+/)
# => #<MatchData ": Ørbæk">
```

According to [Character Properties from Ruby Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties):

> `/\p{Word}/` - A member of one of the following Unicode general category Letter, Mark, Number, Connector_Punctuation

Answer (score 2):

You can use \p{Word} instead:

```
irb(main):001:0> 'The name of the city is: Ørbæk'.match(/:\s\p{Word}+/)
=> #<MatchData ": Ørbæk">
```

Answer (score 1):

If the word you want to match contains just letter characters, then use `\p{L}` :

```
match(/:\s\p{L}+/)
```